Button click changes color of another button in Jetpack Compose
I have 2 buttons. ButtonA is yellow, ButtonB is green. When I click the ButtonA, I’d like it to change to green and also change ButtonB to yellow.
I’ve searched for this but can’t find an answer anywhere. Maybe not using correct search terms.
I tried making ButtonA like a toggle button with var selected by remember { … thinking I could do the same for ButtonB but couldn’t make it work. I’m still a bit new to jetpack.

means you want to swap the color of the button?

Yes, that is correct. Just swap the containerColor between 2 buttons

Any thing you want extra?

I actually found some code to do this. It seemed a bit verbose but I ended up not doing anything with the code anyway. I might revisit it in the future.
